# PATH is not being refershed in VS Studio Power shell environment?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, path

I have added MingGW to my path a couple of days ago and I have turned off my computer yet I find that the path has not been refreshed. I currently have a Windows 11 OS. I have to run this command which I found on this site to get it to work in the current environment of VS Studio.

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
```

I just checked and the PowerShell prompts that I use outside the PATH have loaded.  The one in VS Studio is not recognizing the update.  Just to clear the update is this:

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

This allows me to compile C++ files inside the terminal. Any thoughts to why VS Studio is not recognizing the update?

UPDATE:
I decided to see what the kill the terminal button does and I restarted the VS Studio, and it seems to be working now without that command I found this site. Any explanations on this behavior would kindly be appericated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment of a process is established when the process is launched.
Specifically, the PATH environment variable is included in the process's
environment as it is at that moment, and is never retrieved again during
the entire lifetime of the process.

This is why changes to the PATH made after VS was started cannot be taken
in account by VS.

When you ended and restarted VS, the environment of the new process
was created and included the new PATH variable.

Comment: +1 This is very interesting and very informative.